# SQL: How to save order in sql query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have PostgreSQL database and I try to print all my users (Person).

When I execute this query

```
-- show owners 
-- sorted by maximum cars amount
SELECT p.id
  FROM car c JOIN person p ON c.person_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id
  ORDER BY COUNT(p.name) ASC;
```

I get all owners sorted by cars amount

Output: `3 2 4 1`

And all order goes wrong when I try to link owner id.

```
SELECT *
FROM person p
WHERE p.id IN (
  SELECT p.id
  FROM car c JOIN person p ON c.person_id = p.id
  GROUP BY p.id
  ORDER BY COUNT(p.name) ASC);
```

Output: `1 2 3 4` and other data

You see than order is wrong. So here is my question how can I save that order?

Comment: Why do you need to complicate things and use the second way when the first way works just fine?

Comment: Sorry, what the way you talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I mean first and second query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untangle the mess. Aggregate first, join later:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM   person p
JOIN  (
   SELECT person_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   car
   GROUP  BY person_id
   ) c ON c.person_id = p.id
ORDER  BY c.cnt;
```

See:

- [Multiple array_agg() calls in a single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27622398/multiple-array-agg-calls-in-a-single-query/27626358#27626358)
- [Join a count query on generate_series() and retrieve Null values as '0'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413715/join-a-count-query-on-generate-series-and-retrieve-null-values-as-0/13414797#13414797)

No need to join to `person` twice. This should be fastest if you count *most or all rows*.
For a *small selection*, **correlated subqueries** are faster:

```sql
SELECT p.*
FROM   person p
ORDER  BY (SELECT count(*) FROM car c WHERE c.person_id = p.id)
WHERE  p.id BETWEEN 10 AND 20;  -- some very selective predicate
```

As for your original: [`IN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-IN) takes a ***set*** on the right hand, order of elements is ignored, so `ORDER BY` is pointless in the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Instead Of `subquery` use `join`. Try this.

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   person p
       JOIN (SELECT p.id,
                    Count(p.NAME)cnt
             FROM   car c
                    JOIN person p
                      ON c.person_id = p.id
             GROUP  BY p.id) b
         ON p.id = b.id
ORDER  BY cnt ASC
```

Comment: Oh why do you use `p.*` instead of `*`?

Comment: To get only the p columns in the result.

Comment: You don't need the `join` in the subquery.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Ok, and how can I connect two tables without join operation?