# Calculate table column using over table on server side

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

Suppose, there are two tables in db:

Table `registries`:

```
       Column       |            Type             |                           
--------------------+-----------------------------+---------
 registry_id        | integer                     | not null 
 name               | character varying           | not null
 ...
 uploaded_at        | timestamp without time zone | not null
```

Table `rows`:

```
    Column     |            Type             | Modifiers 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 row_id        | character varying           | not null
 registry_id   | integer                     | not null
 row           | character varying           | not null
```

In real world `registries` is just a csv-file and `rows` is lines of the files. In my scala-slick application, I want to know how many lines in each file.

`registries`:

```
1,foo,...
2,bar,...
3,baz,...
```

`rows`:

```
aaa,1,...
bbb,1,...
ccc,2,...
```

desired result:

```
1,foo,... - 2
2,bar,... - 1
3,baz,... - 0
```

My code now is (slick-3.0):

```
def getRegistryWithLength(rId: Int) = {
    val q1 = registries.filter(_.registryId===rId).take(1).result.headOption
    val q2 = rows.filter(_.registryId===rId).length.result
    val registry = Await.result(db.run(q1), 5.seconds)
    val length = Await.result(db.run(q2), 5.seconds)
    (registry, length)
}
```

(`Await` is bad idea, I know it)

How can I do `getRegistryWithLength` using single `sql` query?

I could add column `row_n` into table `registries`, but then I'll be forced to do updating column `row_n` after delete/insert query of `rows` table.

How can I do automatic calculation column `row_n` in table `registries` on db server side?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want exactly.  `number of rows`? Or a row-number for each row? Please clarify. Add sample data and the expected result to clarify. You want an SQL solution, so it's unwise to write a question that only people familiar with scala and slick can understand.

Comment: Apologize, I updated question. It's about count number of `rows`. I hope on scala solution, but if I'll get SQL solution it will be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic query could be:

```
SELECT r.*, COALESCE(n.ct, 0) AS ct
FROM   registry r
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT registry_id, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   rows
   GROUP  BY registry_id
   ) n USING (registry_id);
```

The **`LEFT [OUTER]`** `JOIN` is essential so you do not filter rows from registry without related rows in `rows`.

[`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to return 0 instead of NULL where no related rows are found.

There are many related answers on SO. One here:

- [SQL: How to save order in sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755834/sql-how-to-save-order-in-sql-query/27756141#27756141)

You could wrap this in a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) for convenience:

```
CREATE VIEW reg_rn AS
SELECT ...
```

... which you query like a table.

Aside: It's unwise to use [reserved SQL key words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) as identifiers. `row` is a no-go for a column name (even if allowed in Postgres).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Erwin Brandstetter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter) for awesome answer, using it, I wrote code for my scala-slick application.

Scala code looks much more complicated than plain sql:

```
val registryQuery = registries.filter(_.userId === userId)
val rowQuery = rows groupBy(_.registryId) map { case (regId, rowItems) => (regId, rowItems.length)}
val q = registryQuery joinLeft rowQuery on (_.registryId === _._1) map {
  case (registry, rowsCnt) => (registry, rowsCnt.map(_._2))
}
```

but it works!