# SELECT fields from one table with aggregates from related table

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join, aggregate

Here is a simplified description of 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE jobs(id PRIMARY KEY, description);
CREATE TABLE dates(id PRIMARY KEY, job REFERENCES jobs(id), date);
```

There may be one or more dates per job.

I would like create a query which generates the following (in pidgin):

```
jobs.id, jobs.description, min(dates.date) as start, max(dates.date) as finish
```

I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT id, description,
      (SELECT min(date) as start  FROM dates d WHERE d.job=j.id),
      (SELECT max(date) as finish FROM dates d WHERE d.job=j.id)
FROM jobs j;
```

which works, but looks very inefficient.

I have tried an `INNER JOIN`, but can’t see how to join `jobs` with a suitable aggregate query on `dates`.

Can anybody suggest a clean efficient way to do this?

Comment: You can aggregate already joined "table".  Most likely will use `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @PM77-1 Something like this: `SELECT min(jobs.id),min(jobs.description), min(dates.date) AS start, max(dates.data) AS finish FROM obs INNER JOIN dates ON jobs.id=dates.job GROUP BY jobs.id`. I thought of that, but wondered whether use of `min` for the `job` items was wasteful.

Comment: You do not have to aggregate fields you use for grouping.

Comment: @PM77-1 You’re right, of course. The corrected statement would be: `SELECT jobs.id,min(jobs.description), min(dates.date) AS start, max(dates.data) AS finish FROM obs INNER JOIN dates ON jobs.id=dates.job GROUP BY jobs.id`. However, in my real application, there are additional fields from the `jobs` table which would also need to be listed, similar to the `description` above.

Comment: As always, your Postgres version should be declared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While retrieving all rows: aggregate first, join later:

```
SELECT id, j.description, d.start, d.finish
FROM   jobs j
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT job AS id, min(date) AS start, max(date) AS finish 
   FROM   dates 
   GROUP  BY job
   ) d USING (id);
```

Related:

- [SQL: How to save order in sql query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27755834/sql-how-to-save-order-in-sql-query/27756141#27756141)

#### About `JOIN .. USING`

It's not a "different type of join". `USING (col)` is a ***standard SQL*** (!) syntax shortcut for `ON a.col = b.col`. More precisely, [quoting the manual:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN)

> The `USING` clause is a shorthand that allows you to take advantage of
>   the specific situation where both sides of the join use the same name
>   for the joining column(s). It takes a comma-separated list of the
>   shared column names and forms a join condition that includes an
>   equality comparison for each one. For example, joining *`T1`* and *`T2`* with
>   `USING (a, b)` produces the join condition `ON *T1*.a = *T2*.a AND *T1*.b = *T2*.b`.
>
> Furthermore, the output of `JOIN USING` suppresses redundant columns:
>   there is no need to print both of the matched columns, since they must
>   have equal values. While `JOIN ON` produces all columns from *`T1`* followed
>   by all columns from *`T2`*, `JOIN USING` produces one output column for each
>   of the listed column pairs (in the listed order), followed by any
>   remaining columns from *`T1`*, followed by any remaining columns from *`T2`*.

It's particularly convenient that you can write `SELECT * FROM ...` and joining columns are only listed once.

Comment: I haven’t seen this type of join before. What is `USING` and why won’t `ON d.job=j.id) work?

Comment: @Manngo: Consider the added explanation. `ON d.job=j.id` does not work here, because there is no column `job` in the derived table `d` after I have applied the column alias `id` (with `job AS id`). Either remove the alias or use instead: `ON d.id = j.id` if you can't acquaint yourself with the convenient shortcut `USING (id)`.

Comment: Well, I learned two things for the price of one here. Aggregate before the join, and the USING clause. It also seems that you can get away with aliasing a column to the same as a column name which allows you to include such weirdness as `SELECT id, job AS id FROM dates` which is probably totally useless, but which would help explain why you can’t use an alias in a calculated expression. Thanks for your excellent solution.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Erwin's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34983741/3304426), you can also use a [window clause](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html):

```
SELECT j.id, j.description,
       first_value(d.date) OVER w AS start,
       last_value(d.date) OVER w AS finish
FROM jobs j
JOIN dates d ON d.job = j.id
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY j.id ORDER BY d.date
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING);
```

Window functions effectively group by one or more columns (the `PARTITION BY` clause) and/or `ORDER BY` some other columns and then you can apply some [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) to it, or even a regular aggregate function, without affecting grouping or ordering of any other columns (`description` in your case). It requires a somewhat different way of constructing queries, but once you get the idea it is pretty brilliant.

In your case you need to get the first value of a *partition*, which is easy because it is accessible by default. You also need to look beyond the *window frame* (which ends by default with the current row) to the last value in the *partition* and then you need the `ROWS` clause. Since you produce two columns using the same window definition, the `WINDOW` clause is used here; in case it applies to a single column you can just write the window function in the select list followed by the `OVER` clause and the window definition without its name (`WINDOW w AS (...)`).

Comment: This goes beyond my own experience with window functions (limited to subtotals and getting row numbers). Thanks for this — I’ll need to spend some time learning more about this.