# Select Null in With Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, null, common-table-expression

I'm using PostgreSQL in SQLWorkbenchJ and I'm struggling.

I have a `WITH` statement that selects a date depending on its row number. If the statement cannot find the row number, I want to select null in the date field. This currently doesn't happen, it just selects records where all fields are not null. I'm assuming it is to do with joins but I'm not sure.

The current statement is below. It should return around 50,000 records but it currently returning just under 2000.

```
WITH FifthEnquiry AS
(
  SELECT emailaddress,
         SentDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emailaddress ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rk
  FROM SentEmails
  GROUP BY emailaddress,
           SentDate
),
TenthEnquiry AS
(
  SELECT emailaddress,
         SentDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emailaddress ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rk
  FROM SentEmails
  GROUP BY emailaddress,
           SentDate
),
TwentiethEnquiry AS
(
  SELECT emailaddress,
         SentDate,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emailaddress ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS rk
  FROM SentEmails
  GROUP BY emailaddress,
           SentDate
)
SELECT FifthEnquiry.emailaddress,
       FifthEnquiry.SentDate AS Fith,
       TenthEnquiry.SentDate AS Tenth,
       TwentiethEnquiry.SentDate AS Twentieth,
FROM FifthEnquiry
  JOIN TenthEnquiry ON FifthEnquiry.emailaddress = TenthEnquiry.emailaddress
  JOIN TwentiethEnquiry ON FifthEnquiry.emailaddress = TwentiethEnquiry.emailaddress
WHERE (FifthEnquiry.rk = 5)
AND   (TenthEnquiry.rk = 10)
AND   (TwentiethEnquiry.rk = 20)
```

Comment: Use a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN, depending on what you need.

Comment: Both give the same number of records @FrankHeikens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can largely simplify. And use `LEFT JOIN` to preserve all email addresses with at least 5 rows after `GROUP BY`, even if there is no 10th or 20th row:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT emailaddress, SentDate,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emailaddress
                             ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, SentDate) AS rn
   FROM   SentEmails
   GROUP  BY 1,2
   )
SELECT enq05.emailaddress,
       enq05.SentDate AS fifth,
       enq10.SentDate AS tenth,
       enq20.SentDate AS twentieth
FROM        cte AS enq05
LEFT   JOIN cte AS enq10 ON enq10.emailaddress = enq05.emailaddress
                        AND enq10.rn = 10
LEFT   JOIN cte AS enq20 ON enq20.emailaddress = enq05.emailaddress
                        AND enq20.rn = 20
WHERE  enq05.rn = 5;
```

- You don't need separate CTEs, all three are doing the same. **One CTE** is enough, and obviously faster. Use self-joins with different table aliases in the outer query instead.
- Since we are using **`LEFT JOIN`** now, it matters whether we put additional conditions in the JOIN or the WHERE clause. Conditions in the WHERE clause effectively force Postgres to treat the join like a plain `[INNER] JOIN`. I moved conditions to the JOIN clause accordingly. Details:

  - [Join a count query on a generate_series in postgres and also retrieve Null-values as "0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13413715/join-a-count-query-on-a-generate-series-in-postgres-and-also-retrieve-null-value/13414797#13414797)
- Using `rn`, not `rk` as column alias. It's a "row number", not a "rank". Be aware of the important **difference** in behavior between [`row_number()` and `rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE).
- Add `SentDate` to **`ORDER BY`** as tiebreaker for `(emailaddress, SentDate)` with the same count to get a stable sort order. The way I have it `SentDate IS NULL` comes last per group. You may want to use `NULLS LAST` for descending sort order (not for `COUNT(*)`, which is never NULL):

  - [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- One more subtle detail you need to be aware of: `tenth` and `twentieth` can all be NULL in the result for **two different reasons**, if `SentDate` can be NULL in the underlying table. A NULL value for `tenth` in the result can mean there are less than 10 distinct values for the `emailaddress` or it can mean that NULL is at the 10th position according to your sort order.

Comment: I still get the same issue with this query. Glad it can be shortened though. I still dont see "null" in any of the columns. It only selects email addresses that have minimum of 20 rows if that makes sense

Comment: @ChrisHall: Did you test my latest version? My first draft still had the WHERE conditions force-converting the LEFT JOIN to a plain JOIN. The current version definitely includes *all* email-addresses with at least 5 rows (after grouping!!). You did want to number rows ***after*** grouping, right? Because that's what you are doing now.

Comment: @ChrisHall: I added some more pointers. There are tricky aspects to this query.